# Pointers for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, pointers

I inserted a code in my functions.php file from my child theme to create a pointer in the wordpress admin area. The code is this:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-pointer' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-pointer' );
    add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'my_admin_print_footer_scripts' );
}
function my_admin_print_footer_scripts() {
    $pointer_content = '<h3>Notice:</h3>';
    $pointer_content .= '<p>This is a message that I will still customize"</strong>.</p>';
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
     $('#wp-admin-bar-breeze-topbar').pointer({
         content: '<?php echo $pointer_content; ?>',
         position: 'top',
         close: function() {
             // Once the close button is hit
         }
       }).pointer('open');
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
<?php
}
```

The code works perfectly. What I needed was that when the user clicks the dismiss button, this pointer does not appear anymore. Is there anything I should add here to fix this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This should get it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
     $('#wp-admin-bar-breeze-topbar').pointer({
         content: '<?php echo $pointer_content; ?>',
         position: 'top',
         }
       }).pointer('open');
    $('#wp-admin-bar-breeze-topbar').click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

    });
</script>
```